# Castle Windsor 3.0 ComponentRegistration "ServiceType"

Tags: castle-windsor

I'm moving some code from Castle 2.5.2 to 3.0, I have a set of predefined registrations (in my boot code) that does some stuff based on conventions such as:

```
container.Register
(
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyInDirectory( new AssemblyFilter( "." ) )
        .IncludeNonPublicTypes()
        .Where( t => conventions.IsViewModel( t ) && !conventions.IsExcluded( t ) )
        .WithService.Select( ( type, baseTypes ) => conventions.SelectViewModelContracts( type ) )
        .Configure( r =>
        {
                    r.Properties( PropertyFilter.IgnoreAll );

            if( conventions.IsShellViewModel( r ) )
            {
                r.LifeStyle.Is( LifestyleType.Singleton );
            }
            else
            {
                r.LifeStyle.Is( LifestyleType.Transient );
            }
        } )
);
```

in Windsor 2.5.2 the ComponentRegistration class has a ServiceType property, in 3.0 there is a Services property but is "internal protected".

My conventions handling relies on the fact that I need to know which are the services.

How can I get that info?

.m

Comment: currently I have partially solved it accessing the Services property on the ComponentRegistration using reflection, but is PITA.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't .WithServiceSelect fullfill your need ?

Comment: In which way? the problem is on the ComponentRegistration class that does not expose anymore the information about the ServiceType (or Services it wll be the same).

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same thing today. Solved it like below, which works since we follow some conventions. It don't feel like it is a good solution though...

```
.Configure(x => x.Named("I"+x.Implementation.Name))
```